# Semi transparent navigation bar with a black block behind it (CSS/HTML/JS)

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, transparency

I am working on a website with responsive navigation menu (used Trunk-js for the menu) The menu needed to be semi-transparent. When the mobile view is active everything is great, but when resize the window (desktop version of the website become active) a black div appear behind the menu, and the navigation menu becomes grey. I spent a few hours to find where is the problem without result.

You can find my website here: [enter link description here](http://design.freezoy.com/)

Comment: some code from could help, may you could put the parts that aren't working in some jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your image behind the header.

It seems like it's getting pushed below it.

Try setting your header to this:

```
header.slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}

.content.slide {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

then it should work.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your suggestion. I tried what you suggested and it is solved my problem partially. The bar semi-transparencity is fine now, but the navigation links are now behind the navigation bar (they are now unclickable). I tried z-index: 3; for "nav" but this messed up the mobile version of the navigation menu.